# nth-child for elements 1,6, 7,10, 13 ect

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to use nth-child to target 1,6, 7,10, 13 ect. and some style. I was targeting them individually but this wont work as the content will be automatically generated.

I have 1 large div followed by 2 small divs one above the other then the next row is the opposite 2 small and one large and this is to continue as content is added.

What would be my best option for achieving this ?

Below is the css i am using at the min:

```
div:nth-child(1),div:nth-child(6),div:nth-child(7),
div:nth-child(10),div:nth-child(13){
background:#000;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean 4, not 6.

Comment: Post the code you tried please.

Comment: Assuming @SLaks is correct and you actually mean 1,4,7,10,13, then `:nth-child(3n+1)` should do it.

Comment: another possible chain is when `10` should be `12`.

Comment: It is 6, I have 1 large div followed by 2 small divs one above the other then the next row is the opposite 2 small and one large and this is to continue as content is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have 1 large div followed by 2 small divs one above the other then the next row is the opposite 2 small and one large and this is to continue as content is added.

So the same situation repeats every 6 items. Using `:nth-child(an+b)`, you now know that `a=6`.
2 elements are selected for each group of 6: 1 and 6 (and then 7 and 12 (not 10), 13 and 18, etc). To select the first one, `b=1` is OK. To select the 6th one, `b=0` or `b=6` are OK

That leads to:

```
li:nth-child(6n+1),
li:nth-child(6n) {
  /* sth different */
}
```

Codepen: **http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cypAn**

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfect and also thank you for the detailed answer it has give me a bit more understanding of using nth-child

Answer (score 0):

You should use **nth-child** if you just want to use CSS. See this [article here](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/). There is a nice table at the bottom that can help if you are a visual learner.

Comment: IE has supported nth-child for over three years.

Comment: @Alohci Yeah you are right. Correct me if I am wrong, but it is not supported in IE 8.